# Using Relative Paths in Crontab

Tags: php, centos, cron

I am attempting to use relative paths in my crontab file on CentOS 6.4, so that I do not have to repeat the same absolute path over and over again. At the top of my crontab file, located here: `/etc/crontab`, I have:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/var/www/html/crons
MAILTO=""
HOME=/
```

And each of my commands looks like:

```
*/2 * * * * root /usr/bin/php "cronfile.php" >> "logs/cronfile_"`date +\%Y\%m\%d`".log"
```

I'm expecting that it'll run the `cronfile.php` PHP file in the `/var/www/html/crons` directory, and save the output from this to `/var/www/html/crons/logs/cronfile.log`. However, the file is not being run and the log file is not being created.

The command works fine if I run just:

```
/usr/bin/php "cronfile.php" >> "logs/cronfile_"`date +\%Y\%m\%d`".log"
```

from the command line after `cd`ing into the `/var/www/html/crons` directory.

Please advise, thanks.

Comment: put the directory in the env path (if you must) - don't really see a problem here, makes a lot of sense to use the absolute path, if you cant copy and paste a few times - there's no hope.

Comment: Can you explain how to use the env path? Also, it's not that I can't copy and paste, it's that I would like to avoid redundancy as I know there are quite a few lines and they will be changing frequently due to my needs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After many trials and research, I discovered that the solution was using the `HOME=` variable, not the `PATH=` variable, like so:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=""
HOME=/var/www/html/crons
```

And then each of the lines would just look like:

```
*/2 * * * * root /usr/bin/php cronfile.php >> logs/cronfile_`date +\%Y\%m\%d`.log
```

Hope this helps someone else with the same issue I had in the future.

Answer (score 2):

`/usr/bin` is already in the `PATH` on most systems by default, so you should be able to remove the `PATH` declaration from the top of your crontab.

Your job is running in a bash shell so you could do something like:

```
*/2 * * * * root cd /var/www/html/crons && php cronfile.php >> cronfile_`date +\%Y\%m\%d`.log
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually wanted to include the absolute path only once in the file (rather than every line), and I just found out the solution, so I posted what fixed the issue for me.